# Server Alias Issue

Tags: linux, apache

I got a virtual host setup like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.website.com
        ServerAlias www.sub.website.com sub.website.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/website/public_html
        <Directory /home/website/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        LimitInternalRecursion 20
        #set logging
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel notice
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
#       SuexecUserGroup %1 %1

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-website
#    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -idle-timeout 900 -pass-header Authorization
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-website -socket /var/run/website-php5-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 900 -pass-header Authorization

</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

And I was wondering if I point an A record to the www.sub.website.com do I also need to point an A record over to the sub.website.com as well to make them both land on the same website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both www.sub.website.com and sub.website.com need to point to the same IP, but A record is a bad idea, you should use CNAME.